# sql using query alias in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to get result from query in Management Studio (ms sql). How can I use query result in where not exists clause like below:

```
select res.id
from
(select id, column1 from table1) as res
where not exists (select id from res where column1 is null)
```

Query is more complicated but I want to know how can I use query with alias in from from cluse in where clause using not exists.

Comment: You can't. Consider a CTE instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a note:  You can phrase this logic using `except`:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
except
select t1.id
from table1 t1
where column1 is null;
```

If `table1` is really a complex query, then both this method and the CTE method require evaluating it twice.  Instead, you can use window functions:

```
select id
from (select t1.*,
             sum(case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as cnt_column1_null
      from table1
     ) t1
where cnt_column1_null > 0;
```

Or aggregation:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
group by t1.id
having sum(case when column1 is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used query with aggregation and it's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a number of things when you say your query is more complicated as the simplified scenario provided doesn't fully make sense, but the functionality you're essentially looking for is CTEs ([Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)) as they can be used in this way.

e.g.

```
-- "res" is the CTE, that in the immediate statements, you can then 
-- reference multiple times
WITH res AS (
    SELECT id, column1
    FROM table1
)
SELECT res.id 
FROM res
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM res WHERE .....)
```

Essentially, the CTE is a named alias for a query, that you can then reference using that alias instead of repeating the whole query each time.