# Using Inline Query Alias in Where clause outside of inline Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, alias

I already saw a solution, link [sql using query alias in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986809/sql-using-query-alias-in-where-clause) but it didn't help me much.

My question is how to use inline alias for outer query in where clause because I am getting an error message using inline alias in the outer query in the where condition.

My query is-

```
USE db_Stock_Market;
    GO
    SELECT * FROM STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS
    --The days where there is 2% or more drop
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            Date, Symbol, LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Purchase_price, 100/LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Shares,
            (BID_Close-BID_Open)/BID_Open AS Day_Return, 100 AS Purchase
                FROM STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS
                   )
                    WHERE Day_Return< -0.02
```

Error Message-

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11   Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword  'WHERE'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing derived table alias name

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            Date, Symbol, LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Purchase_price, 100/LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Shares,
            (BID_Close-BID_Open)/BID_Open AS Day_Return, 100 AS Purchase
                FROM STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS
)A WHERE Day_Return< -0.02
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 USE db_Stock_Market;
GO
SELECT * FROM STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS
--The days where there is 2% or more drop
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        Date, Symbol, LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Purchase_price, 
        100/LEAD(BID_Open) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Shares,
        (BID_Close-BID_Open)/BID_Open AS Day_Return, 
        100 AS Purchase
    FROM STOCK_DATA_FOR_ANALYSIS
    ) as X
WHERE Day_Return< -0.02
```