# Using Inline Query Field in Where Condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, inline

I have gone through this solution [Using Inline Query Alias in Where clause outside of inline Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213594/using-inline-query-alias-in-where-clause-outside-of-inline-query)  but its not working for below query

```
select `leads`.*, `departmentdata`.`name` as `department`,
    (
    select activitytype.activity_name
      from activities inner
      join activitytype on activitytype.id = activities.activity_type_id 
     where activities.leadid = leads.id 
       and activities.followup_date >= CURDATE() 
     order by activities.followup_date asc 
     limit 0,1
    )temp1
from `leads` 
left join `departmentdata` on `departmentdata`.`id` = `leads`.`department` 
where activity_name = 'Email'
order by `leads`.`id` desc
```

i am still getting below error.

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'activity_name' in 'where clause'
```

Any help?

Since this is a very big query so removed other fields. Below is the query without putting condition on activity_name fields.

[image]

But when i apply condition on activity_name field then i get above error.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: @D-Shih I have added sample data with my query in which condition on activity_name fields is not applied. But When i apply condition in activity_name table then i get above error.

Comment: You could put that where into your inline select. But why don't you make a join out of this? It seems to be what you want considering the "where activities.leadid = leads.id" in your inline select.

Comment: Order of execution means your column is not visible to the where clause, you would have to implement the solution in the question you linked to, however it appears you could simply implement your subquery as an `exists`? To be certain we'd need to see some sample data and expected results, ie, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The column name as aliased is temp1...

Answer (score 0):

See if moving your where to your inline select gives you your result.
I wonder if you need to join activitytype but can't really tell because I don't know what your expected outcome is and there is no test data.

```
select
    `leads`.*,
    `departmentdata`.`name` as `department`,
    (
        select
            activitytype.activity_name
        from
            activities
        inner join
            activitytype
        on
            activitytype.id = activities.activity_type_id
        where
            activities.leadid = leads.id and
            activities.followup_date >= CURDATE() and
            activities.activity_name = 'Email'
        order by
            activities.followup_date asc
        limit 0,1
    ) as temp1
from
    `leads` 
left join
    `departmentdata`
on
    `departmentdata`.`id` = `leads`.`department` 
order by
    `leads`.`id` desc
```

Comment: I tried above solution but that did not work because my query also pulls other records of Leads that do not have activity type Email. Moreover, the join on activity table make the query bulky because activity table is growing table and may have millions of rows. Somehow i need to put condition on activity type in the outer Where clause